# AngularJS - Uncaught Error: Service name expected from myApp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, config, bootstrapping

I'm trying to implement a Facebook provider (angular-facebook.js) as show in the below plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/dDAmvdCibv46ULfgKCd3?p=preview

However, I've made a bit of a hash with my config files. The plnkr example doesn't use a route provider so I'm unsure how to structure my .config to both utilize the route provider *and* initialize my Facebook implementation:

**Current but Not Working**

```
'use strict';
var myApp = angular.module('myApp ', ['facebook'])
.config(
    ['FacebookProvider',
    function(FacebookProvider){
        var myAppId = '4605923966';

        FacebookProvider.init(myAppId);
    },
    function($routeProvider)
    {
        $routeProvider.when('/admin/area',
        {
            templateUrl: 'app/admin/area/index.html'
        });

    }]
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `config` only takes one function as a parameter, so you need to inject both `FacebookProvider` and `$routeProvider` into it like this:

```
'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module('myApp ', ['facebook'])
.config(['FacebookProvider', '$routeProvider',
    function(FacebookProvider, $routeProvider) {
        var myAppId = '4605923966';

        FacebookProvider.init(myAppId);

        $routeProvider.when('/admin/area', {
            templateUrl: 'app/admin/area/index.html'
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: Legend, thank you. I did try something similar but I think I forgot to pass the '$routeProvider' into the start of the .config- thanks again!